# Could it be correct to say "very little people attended the event"?"

Tags: quantifiers

I know 'little' is for uncountable nouns and 'people' is a countable noun.
But, could it work as the noun 'hair'? When the quantity is way too big to be counted, it's considered uncountable, or does 'people' mantain it's countability no matter the quantity?

Answer (score 2):

*Some* nouns in English *can* be used both countably and not:

- "He cut two hairs," vs. "He cut his hair."
- "The waters of the Guainía merge with that of the Amazon, vs. "There is water in the glass."
- "There are many fish in the lake," vs. "Trout and salmon are similar fishes."

However, people **are** always countable. Saying "very little people," in English, would imply the attendees were of rather short stature, perhaps as [leprechauns](https://www.britannica.com/art/leprechaun).

It is just one of the many idiosyncrasies of English. *sigh*

Comment: ... so we have to say 'very **few** people'.

Comment: @KateBunting, unless they **are** vertically challenged.